# TextFormField retrieves the focus and reassigns the initial value when the keyboard is closed

Tags: flutter

I find myself working with TextFormField hand in hand with DropdownButton. There is a strange process going on inside the view. I put the steps below:

1. To the TexFormField, I'm assigning an initial value:  `controller: _nameController..text = datumAdministrative.name`.

[image: initial value]

2. I enter a new value to the TextFormField.

[image: new value]

3. When the DropdownButton is deployed, the keyboard is closed the whole Widget is redrawn, which causes the TextFormField to recover its initial value and does not keep the new value entered.

[image: keyboard is closed]

Is there any way to avoid, that the TextFormField returns to its initial value when selecting DropdownButton? I would appreciate if you could help me with a post or feedback.

Code Scaffold:

```
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
  appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: ColorsTheme.primary,
      leading: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'administrativeListData');
        },
        child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
            child: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.arrowLeft)),
      ),
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(datumAdministrative.name +
          ' ' +
          datumAdministrative.lastNameFather),
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false),
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      ImageBackground(),
      _sizeBoxHeight(),
      Container(
        child: Form(
          key: formValidator.formKey,
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              _containerImageUser(context, datumAdministrative),
              _sizeBoxHeight(),

             
              CustomCardExpansionTile(
                title: Constants.administrativeData,
                icon: FontAwesomeIcons.addressBook,
                widget: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    child: responsiveDataAdministrative(context)),
              ),

             
              CustomCardExpansionTile(
                  title: Constants.addressInformationAdministrative,
                  icon: FontAwesomeIcons.houseUser,
                  widget: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      child: responsiveAddressInformationAdministrative(
                          context))),

              
              CustomCardExpansionTile(
                  title: Constants.userDataSystem,
                  icon: FontAwesomeIcons.idCard,
                  widget: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                      child: responsiveInformationSystemAdministrative(
                          context))),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Code TextFormField:

```
TextFormField(
  controller: _nameController..text = datumAdministrative.name,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  textInputAction: null,
  textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
  onChanged: (value) => formValidator.name = value,
  validator: (value) {
    if (formValidator.fieldValidText(value)) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return Constants.nameAdministrativeMessage;
    }
  });
```

Comment: can you this full widget?

Comment: Sure, I edit my question and put the complete Widget

Comment: Where `CustomTextField`  is coming from? Also, can you provide unique `key:ValueKey()` on TextFiled, and can you provide simple widget with producing the same issue that you are facing?

Comment: `CustomTextField` It is a Widget of type TextFormField. `key:ValueKey()` , It is located within the Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you set the value for the `text` property of `TextEditingController` inside the `build` method. So, it will be invoked whenever the widget rebuilds, causing the value for the field back to the initial one.

The docs actually tells about it:

### [text property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController/text.html)

> Setting this will notify all the listeners of this
> TextEditingController that they need to update (it calls
> notifyListeners). For this reason, this value should only be set
> between frames, e.g. in response to user actions, **not during the
> build**, layout, or paint phases.

To fix it, you should remove the cascade notation here:

```dart
controller: _nameController..text = datumAdministrative.name,
```

Do it inside `initState()` instead:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
   _nameController.text = datumAdministrative.name;
}
```